# how to put variable inside append jquery

Tags: jquery

**script**

javascript  how to put variable inside in append

```
    $(function () {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Menu/getpageMenu",
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var opt = new Option(data[i].Title, data[i].Id);                            
                        $('#target').append('<input type ="checkbox" name="menu">' + opt+ '</input>');
                    }

                }

            });
        });
    });
```

[image]

data is not showing.

Comment: what is `target` ?

Comment: Bugs aside, your HTML is not valid. `<input />` is self closing and `<option>` elements should be placed inside a `<select>` - not randomly inside a form

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(function () {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Menu/getpageMenu",
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        //var opt = new Option(data[i].Title, data[i].Id);                            
                        $('#target').append('<input type ="checkbox" name="menu" value="'+data[i].Id+'">' + data[i].Title+ '</input>');
                    }

                }

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: OP want to use variable in append html string. So I have give way for it

Comment: anyway, `name="menu[]"`, you will get only one `$_GET['menu']` with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `Option` and simply parse the JSON and get the HTML as desired

```
 $(function () {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Menu/getpageMenu",
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                           
                        $('#target').append('<input value="'+data[i].Id+'" type ="checkbox"  name="menu" />' + data[i].Title );
                    }

                }

            });
        });
    });
```

Here, the checkbox `value` will be `data[i].Id` and the checkbox text will be `data[i].Title`

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var opt = new Option(data[i].Title, data[i].Id);                            
   $('#target').append('<div><input type ="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="' + data[i].Id + '">' + data[i].Title + '</div>);
}
```

You create a new object from your existing object, what can not displayed as you want. Use your original response object `data`